# Bianchi identity of a non-Abelian gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, differentiation, yang-mills

How can one prove the Bianchi identity of a non-Abelian gauge theory? i.e.
$$
\epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda \sigma}(D_{\nu}F_{\lambda \sigma})^a=0
$$

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Use the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity)
$$\sum_{\mu,\nu,\lambda~{\rm cycl.}} [D_{\mu},[ D_{\nu}, D_{\lambda}]]~=~0. $$

Answer (score 6):

using Jacobi identity as mentioned in one of the answers, its very easy to prove the Bianchi identity

\begin{align}\tfrac{1}{ig}
[D_\mu,\,[D_\nu,\,D_\lambda]]\psi &= [D_\mu,\,F_{\nu\lambda}] \psi \\
&= D_\mu (F_{\nu\lambda}\psi) - F_{\nu \lambda}D_\mu \psi \\
&= D_\mu F_{\nu\lambda}\psi + F_{\nu \lambda}D_\mu\psi - F_{\nu\lambda}D_\mu\psi \\
&= D_\mu F_{\nu\lambda}\psi \, .
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$D_\mu F_{\nu\lambda} + D_\nu F_{\lambda\mu} + D_\lambda F_{\mu\nu} = 0$$
which proves the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange. This site supports TeX style typesetting for mathematics. I edited your post to use this feature. Please take a look at how it was done so you can do it yourself in future posts.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use
$$
[D_{\nu},D_{\mu}] = igF_{\nu \mu}
$$